# How to find the number of sides of a dice with an unspecified sides

Tags: probability

Please I need help on how to go about solving this question:

**A dice has $n$ sides with numbers $1,2,3,4,...,n$ marked on it. If the probability that a particular number appears at least once when the dice is rolled thrice is $217/729$, then how many sides does the dice have?**

I was thinking that if the number was one, then this is how I can go about the solution: the probability of one appearing at least once will be something like this

$$\frac{1}{n}\times \frac{2}{n}\times \frac{3}{n}$$

Then I equate it to $217/729$ and find for $n$:

$$\frac{1}{n}\times \frac{2}{n}\times \frac{3}{n}=\frac{217}{729}$$

But since the question didn't give any number, but rather said "a particular number appears at least once" so I became a bit confused on how to solve it. Please any help on how to go about it?

Comment: Doesn't matter which number.  Say it is $1$, they all have the same probability of being observed in some chain.

Comment: @lulu Okay. Please so how do I go about it

Comment: Well, suppose there are $n$ faces.  What's the probability that you see no $1's$ in three tosses?

Comment: $1 - \frac{n-1}{n}$ Please something like this or

Comment: 729 is hugely suggestive... if there is an answer at all, $n^3=729$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to assume here that the dice is fair, that is, that when we throw it the probability that a particular side appear is the same for every side. This mean that the probability that, after a throw, the number that appear is one will be $1/n$, where $n$ is the number of sides of the dice.

Then the probability that a one appear at least once in three throws will be the complementary probability that no one appear at all, that is
$$
1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{3}
$$

Equating the above with the given probability, we have that

$$
\frac{n-1}{n}=\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{217}{729}}\iff n=\frac1{1-\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{217}{729}}}=9
$$

Answer (score 2):

If you roll an $n$-sided die three times, the probability that a particular number (it doesn't matter which number that is, if the die is fair) *doesn't* appear at all is $(\frac{n-1}{n})^3$.  The inverse of this, $1-(\frac{n-1}{n})^3$, is the probability that the given number appears at least once.

So, you want to find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1-(\frac{n-1}{n})^3 = \frac{217}{729}$.  Multiplying both sides by $729n^3$ to get rid of the fractions, and doing some more algebra, gives the cubic equation $217 n^3 - 2187 n^2 + 2187 n - 729 = 0$.  This has three roots, but two of them are complex and thus not a valid answer the question.  The other one is $n = 9$.

If using [the Cubic Formula](http://www.math.utah.edu/%7Ewortman/1060text-tcf.pdf) or trying to factor the polynomial is too tedious for you, an easier approach is to note that $\sqrt[3]{729} = 9$, so the number of sides must be a multiple of 9.  So try plugging in $n = 9, 18, 27, 36, ...$ until you get a solution.